# Should I start with Angry Birds or Angry Birds Seasons?

Tags: ios, angry-birds

There are two versions of Angry Birds on the app store: [The original](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8), and [an "expandalone" with a couple sets of seasonal levels](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/angry-birds-seasons/id398157641?mt=8) (Halloween and Christmas, currently).

I haven't played either one. Does the expandalone's level design assume a familiarity with the original game? Which one should I play first?

Comment: Pre-emptive snarky comment: Because 99 cents is such a *huge investment* that I can't risk making any mistakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I would suggest starting with the original Angry Birds**, simply because it contains much more levels than the Seasons edition. (The original Angry Birds has 11 worlds as of this post, and the Seasons edition has 3 Halloween worlds and 25 Christmas levels.)

The Seasons edition is more of an extension to the original.

Comment: In addition Angry Birds is easier than the Season version, and the different type of birds are introduced smoothly so you can take confidence with them.